# How to make responsive AdSense unit change its size on browser resize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, adsense

I am using responsive AdSense unit in advanced mode. It works well until I decide to **resize my browser window**. Ad does not resize as specified in media query.

```
<style>
.myad { width: 320px; height: 50px; }
@media(min-width: 500px) { .myad { width: 468px; height: 60px; } }
@media(min-width: 800px) { .myad { width: 728px; height: 90px; } }
</style>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle myad"
     style="display:inline-block"
     data-ad-client="XXX"
     data-ad-slot="XXX"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

The CSS is correct. In Firebug, I can see media rules **crossed off** and replaced by something like:

```
element.style {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 90px;
  width: 728px;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no issue with your responsive Google Ads.

The Google Ads will not resize themselves automatically when you change the browser size. If you refresh your browser then Google Adsense will display/serve new ads with a size that will match the current size of your browser/page.

I tried to find documentation to verify my statement but I was not able to find anything relevant. My answer is based on my experience from using responsive Google ads and testing them.

---

**Update 30/05/2019 - ALL AD UNITS RESPONSIVE BY DEFAULT**

An email was sent by Google to Adsense publishers on the 30th of May 2019 informing about upcoming improvements to ad units.

The email says:

> We’re committed to continuously investing in the modernisation of our advertising products. As a result, there are some important changes we're making to some AdSense features that you have used or configured in the past. Your **Ads** tab will be updated in the coming weeks to reflect the following changes:
>
> **Ad sizes**
>   We've made it easier to create and manage ad units. All ad units will be created **Responsive** by default to adjust to different screen sizes on mobile and desktop for increased performance and flexibility. If you do need further customisation, you’ll still be able to create custom sized ad units.

So, in the coming weeks **all ads will be Responsive be default**. Here are two Google Adsense help pages with more information:

[About responsive ad units](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689)

[Create a responsive ad unit](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3543893)

Comment: Can you provide any source for that statement? Responsiveness would be pretty useless without this feature.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any source. I have used responsive Google Ads on my websites and have noticed that they do not resized upon resizing the browser window. Google loads new ads only when they are first served/loaded.

Comment: I spent ages wondering why my ads didn't resize!  Tried changing styles, adding div tags ... the answer is obvious, once you read it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689

> For example, if you have a  with a width of 30% and you place our responsive ad code within the , then depending on the width of the user's screen, we’ll automatically serve different ad sizes. If your page is viewed on a tablet with a width of 1024px, we'll serve a 307x250 ad, and if it's viewed on a 21" desktop PC with a 1680px width, we'll serve a 504x60 ad.

Meaning when the screen changes it keeps whichever was the first one to load. It's not *actually* responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I read on adsense blog that they plan to fix that, which means that its a knows issue.